# Switch - How to check white space?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WHITE_SPACE 0
#define NOT_WHITE_SPACE 1

void main() {

    char c;
    int code;

    printf("Please give a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if (c== " " ||  c== "\n" || c== "\t")
            code = WHITE_SPACE;
    else:
            code = NOT_WHITE_SPACE;
    }

    printf("%d\n", code);

}
```

I want to convert `if-else` statement to `switch`.

When I'm trying `case " "` or `case "\n"` or `case "\t"`, I'm getting `error case label does not reduce to an integer constant`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: begin with anything within "double quotes" is not a char so c== " " is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal string like e.g. `" "` is actually an *array* of (read-only) characters. As other arrays, it decays to a pointer to its first element. That means `c == " "` will compare the character in `c` with the *pointer* to the first character of `" "`.

To get a literal character, use single quotes instead, as in `' '`:

```
if (c== ' ' ||  c== '\n' || c== '\t')
```

Now when you know how to use literal characters, you can use them inside a `switch` for your `case` labels.

But of course, don't reinvent the wheel, use the standard [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) function instead:

```
if (isspace(c))
```

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, there is no way the original code you posted works, it is not valid C.

`switch` statements only work on integers, so you have to use the proper character constants such as `' '`. And not string literals `" "`. Example:

```
switch(ch)
{
  case ' ':
  case '\n':
  case '\t':
    puts("whitespace");
  break;

  default:
    puts("not whitespace");
}
```

That being said, there is no need to roll out stuff like this manually. `#include <ctype.h>` then call the function `isspace` instead.